# Merge identically named columns (with text in rows) in one dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, aggregate

I have a dataframe with 2300+ columns and 300 rows. Columns are named in pairs =

```
df<- read.csv(file = "RmergeTest.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", check.names = FALSE)
df
    SNP_1 SNP_1 SNP_2 SNP_2 SNP_3 SNP_3 etc....
1       A     T     T     G     G     C
2       A     T     T     G     G     C
3       A     T     T     G     N     N
4       A     T     T     G     G     C
```

I would like to combine/merge/etc each column pair =

```
   SNP_1 SNP_2 SNP_3
1     AT    TG    GC
2     AT    TG    GC
3     AT    TG    NN
4     AT    TG    GC
```

Comment: Why are your columns dynamic while your rows are static?  A general practice when working with tables is to have the number of columns be static and the rows to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the data.frame into groups based on similar column names using `split.default`. Then, you can paste the columns in each sub-group together suing `Reduce(paste0, ...)`

```
sapply(split.default(df, names(df)), function(a) Reduce(paste0, a))
#     SNP_1 SNP_2 SNP_3
#[1,] "AT"  "TG"  "GC" 
#[2,] "AT"  "TG"  "GC" 
#[3,] "AT"  "TG"  "NN" 
#[4,] "AT"  "TG"  "GC"
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(SNP_1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A"), SNP_1 = c("T", 
"T", "T", "T"), SNP_2 = c("T", "T", "T", "T"), SNP_2 = c("G", 
"G", "G", "G"), SNP_3 = c("G", "G", "N", "G"), SNP_3 = c("C", 
"C", "N", "C")), .Names = c("SNP_1", "SNP_1", "SNP_2", "SNP_2", 
"SNP_3", "SNP_3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4"))
```